# Selecting which project under a solution to debug or run in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ide

This one should be easy. I just can't figure out what to search for...

For this one solution I created a unit test project, and I've been adding unit tests frantically. When I went back to try to run the original project after making all the unit tests pass I realized that I couldn't figure out how to debug the original project.

In other words, every time I try to "debug" (e.g., by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>), Visual Studio will run the unit tests. So the question is how do I run various projects in a single solution? How do I select which one will run when I want it to?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

[You can right click on the project and choose to set as startup project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1awth7y.aspx)

Comment: There's a 3rd way too - right clicking on the solution and you can choose multiple startup projects.

Comment: I believe F5 starts the startup project.  You can also right click on the solution and set it to start multiple projects on F5.

Comment: F5 will start debugging the current Startup Project, not the one corresponding to the current source code file.

Comment: Yea, if you want to go back to using f5 you need to select "Setup as startup project"; otherwise, you need to "Debug"->Start new Instance as someone said below. I don't know how I didn't see that one before. Thanks :)!

Answer (score 7):

You can right-click a project and set it as the Startup Project.  It then is debugged when you press F5, or run when you press Ctrl-F5.

You can right-click a project and select `Debug / Start new instance` to debug a project that is not the startup project.

On a side note, you can run / debug the unit tests without setting the unit test project as the startup one.  There are icons (and keyboard shortcuts) in the toolbar to run or debug unit tests at various scopes (if not visible right-click your toolbar and select Test Tools).

Answer (score 7):

1) In the Solution-Explorer, right-click on the project that is the project for the executable assembly, and select "Set as Startup Project". This will make the project show in bold, and will be run automatically when you press F5.

2) Alternatively, in the Solution-Explorer, right-click on the project that is the project for the executable assembly, and select "Debug -> Start New Instance". This will start the debug session immediately.

Answer (score 6):

This was my quickly Startup Project change way for me:

1. **Tools** > **Customize** > **Commands Tab**.
2. Choose **Toolbar** selection
3. Select **Standard** toolbar. 
   [image: Customize Window]
4. Choose a place by mouse for new icon on menu preview and click **Add Command...** button
5. Go to **Project** item on **Categories** list on opened **Add Command** window.
6. Select **Set as Startup Project** item on **Commands** list
   [image]
7. Now, you can **Set** current project **as Startup Project** just one click
   [image]

But today I want more quickly way, then I finally found a way to set a shortcut for Set as Startup Project menu.

Just set a shortcut for "***ClassViewContextMenus.ClassViewProject.Debug.Startnewinstance***" item at **Tools** > **Options** > **Enviroment** > **Keyboard**

*I set Ctrl + Alt + Shift + F5*

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to debug a single console app project, and it is as simple as that:

1. Select the project in the Visual Studio run menu:
   [image]
2. You can even add debug parameters in the project properties:
   [image]

That's it. You can right-click the project and press "Start new instance", [image]

or press F5, or click the "play" button visible in the first image.

Answer (score 0):

Now in Visual Studio 2020, when you right click on the solution and click on Properties you have the choice of running a single or multiple project or multiple :

[image]

If you choose single you can choose here : [image]

And with multiple startup projects, you can run multiple at the same time !