# Visual studio debugger run other project

Tags: visual-studio

I am new on VS, I have two project and when I am trying to run project B , the VS always run project A. how can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting which project under a solution to debug or run in Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004685/selecting-which-project-under-a-solution-to-debug-or-run-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 1):

load both project in vs and set default project which you want to run .
Right Click on the project you want to run in the Solution Explore then click on Set as startup project and run.